# How to download/mirror my website built using Iweb on mac when i have no access to hosting?

Tags: python-3.x, clone, httrack, iweb

I created a site using Iweb in mac few years ago. But now I don't have the domain.sites file to edit the site. Also, I don't have access to the hosting account since it has been long I have been active on it. I used httrack website copier and dozens of other tools on windows to clone the site, but i am not getting good results. Some resources are not loading on offline version. How can i mirror the site ?

I also tried the python Wpull and linux wget but no good results.

My site is: http://www.smith-lakehomes.com

Answer (score 0):

One way is to manually get all HTML, CSS and JS files via the Chrome 'Inspect' mode imho.

Use the 'Elements' tab for all the HTML and the sources-tab for all JS, CSS etc.

[image: Sources-Tab]